# How to write data to excel without over riding existing data in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I want to write data to excel in my nodejs api without over riding the existing data in it. How can i do that ?

Comment: Do you want to append the data ? What does existing excel looks like and what do you want to achieve? Also it will be a bit helpful if you can share your sample code and what issue you are facing.

Comment: I want to append data to the existing sheet. I want to write JSON format data into Excel without over writing the existing data